# Example of a curve "being defined over" some field $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In my self-study of Lec.15 of [Belyi Maps and Dessins d'Enfants](https://math.mit.edu/%7Esschiavo/Courses/Belyi-Sp21/index.php), I came across the following definition

> [Section 3 of Belyi's Theorem] Let X be a projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Then X is *is defined over* a field $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ if there exists a collection of polynomials with coefficients in K whose vanishing locus is isomorphic to X.

I was not quite sure about the last part `vanishing locus is isomorphic to X`.
There is an example given after this definition saying;

> E: $y^2 = x^3 - 1$ is evidently defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

How do we know that some collection of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$  whose vanishing locus is isomorphic to E?

Comment: Well, $y^2-x^3+1\in\Bbb Q[x,y]$, right?

Comment: Because the polynomial $y^2 - x^3 + 1$ has only rational coefficients?

Comment: yeah.. I think I just overlooked that simple fact!
Thank you!